# Executing third party code

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface

We have a WPF (Windows Forms is also applicable) application and for some functionality we are dependent on other teams.  I am looking for a best way to execute the functionaity from other teams without compromising the stability of our main app.

The other teams functionality will include some GUIs and which may be making calls to some other services/databases etc. And our concern is executing the other teams functionality on UI thread as we are not sure about their coding standards like are they following proper techniques about Background thread when executing services. We have the ability to suggest them on API design to our choice.  I am thinking of following two options

1. The API will Async call, but will take dispatcher as input. Not very confident about passing dispatcher around
2. Provide API explicity into service/GUI methods so we can call services on background thread and pass the model to the GUI when completed. But it will involve lot more work on our side.

Or there any better ways to handle when dealing with stabiltiy of our application while executing other teams code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 3:

Pass them an `Action<Action>` called "UIThreadInvoker" or something that then can store somewhere in a static reference and use that every time they need something done on the UI Thread:

Your Side:

```
//App_Startup or somewhere during initialization
TheirApi.UIThreadInvoker = x => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(x);
```

Their Side:

```
  public class TheirAPI
   {
       public static Action<Action> UIThreadInvoker {get;set;}

       public void SomeMethod()
       {
           //Pass SomeOtherMethod() to the UIThreadInvoker
           UIThreadInvoker(SomeOtherMethod);
       }

       public void SomeOtherMethod()
       {
           //this will be executed by your dispatcher
       }
   }
```